How to name pv modules and inverters from CEC Library?
I´m doing another project and after checking both data bases for inverters and modules in CEC, I found that the ones that I have to use are there, those options are the following:
Module: Trina Solar TSM-595DE20
Inverter: Shenzhen Growatt New Energy Co - Ltd : GROWATT 33000TL3-US [480V]
But I don´t know how to call them so I can get my system done because I got a KeyError by writting it as it´s shown in the data base. Heres is my code:
location = Location(latitude = 43.32705299783537, longitude = -3.0227735318548272, tz = "Europe/Madrid", altitude = 26, name = 'Nautica')
modules = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('CECMod')
inverters = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('CECInverter')
module = modules['Trina_Solar_TSM_595DE20'] 
inverter = inverters['Shenzhen Growatt New Energy Co - Ltd : GROWATT 33000TL3-US [480V]'] 
temp_par = TEMPERATURE_MODEL_PARAMETERS['sapm']['open_rack_glass_glass']
system = PVSystem(surface_tilt = 20, surface_azimuth = 141, module_parameters = module, inverter_parameters = inverter, temperature_model_parameters = temp_par, modules_per_string = 16, strings_per_inverter = 3) #Condiciones reales de instalación, simulación por inversor
modelchain = ModelChain(system, location, aoi_model = 'physical', spectral_model = 'no_loss')

KeyError: 'Trina_Solar_TSM_595DE20'
KeyError: 'Shenzhen Growatt New Energy Co - Ltd : GROWATT 33000TL3-US [480V]'


Please do not ask the same question in two places at the same time.

Trina Solar TSM-595DE20 is not in pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('CECMod')
I also found that some modules in CEC database are not updated in the database called by pvlib.
I recommend defining a manual module by using the data in the CEC database or manufacturer datasheet. You can estimate the other factors (such as 'I_L_ref', 'I_o_ref', etc) that are not indicated in CEC database/manufacturer datasheet with ivtools.sdm.fit_cec_sam.
